# Is there a better way of reading the name of the file from the command line?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc ,char *argv[]){
    int *array;
    int pl;
    string filename;
    if (argc == 2){
        filename = argv[1];
    }
    fstream f(filename, ios::in| ios::out); 
    f >> pl;
    array = new int[pl];
    for(int i=0; i<pl; i++){
        f>>array[i];
        cout<<array[i]<<endl;
    }
    delete [] array;
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried the above and it works well, but is there a better way to do it? Say, for instance, if I was trying to do it from a class method.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Tip: In C++ avoid `new[]` and use `std::vector`.

Comment: Better in what ways?

Comment: You can execute the same code in a class method than you can in int main(). With that said I agree with the other comment remove the usage of `new`

Comment: @tadman will fix but i am not that good with vectors

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili in a way that is sorter or i ma doing something that is not needed

Comment: @drescherjm if this works in a class as well then i am all good thnx

Comment: `fstream f(filename, ios::in| ios::out);` do you really want to open this file for reading and writing?

Comment: In a class you can pass the filename argument in a `std::string`

Comment: I don't know how you can be "not that good" as they're a lot simpler than using `new[]`, and take about five minutes to understand. Mostly you just need to learn the difference between `push_back()` and `emplace_back()` but emplace is only really important when dealing with structures or complex objects. They work largely the same as C arrays, but also allow easy iteration with `for (auto&& x : y)` which is super nice.

Comment: @drescherjm not really so i should remove the out or open an ifstream ?

Comment: @tadman one big problem i have with vectors is that if i remove something from them then it shrinks and changes the place where the contents were correct?

Comment: If you're adding or deleting elements from a vector, sure, you might see that happen (iterator and/or pointer invalidation), but you'll also have to do that *manually* if you're working with a `new[]` allocated array. If you need durable pointers to elements in your vector you might want to use a different container, and there are many to choose from. It depends on what you're doing. With direct allocations you have to allocate a new slab, copy, delete the old one, and hope you did that in the correct order.

Comment: Do you really try to open a file using the empty string as file name? If you know there's an issue with the input (in this case the number of command line parameters being incorrect), you should return a non-zero exit code instead of proceeding with some logic that has no chance of succeeding. Btw: `auto array = std::make_unique<int[]>(static_cast<size_t>(pl));` would be an option that automatically destroys the array when exiting the scope.

Comment: There are libraries out there that help parse command line arguments. A quick google search gives this:  https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B%20command%20line%20parsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is perfectly fine and is along the fastest to achieve your goal. Anything else, including classes, just need more effort/typing to do the same with no advantage. I would only add a minimal error handling:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc ,char *argv[]){
    if (argc!=2) {
        cerr << "please provide a filename as argument." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    string const filename(argv[1]);

    // etc...
    // etc...
    // etc...

    return 0;
}
```

And if you will ever need anything more complex than just a single "filename" parameter, please checkout the really great cli11 https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11 library.